# Yolov8n-pose in swift

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, coremltools

I want to use yolov8n-pose model that converted to mlpackage by coremltools

But when using it inside my app the output contain the multarray with dimension of (1 * 56*8600)

This mean the postprocessing (like nonMaxSuppression) not included in package and I must do it my self. What could I do to inherit it inside mlpackage?

I expect an array of [1*56*3]
But recived [1*56*8600]

Comment: You have to train it while making the ml file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.